Tridion Sites 10 - Rest Content Manager Api
I am looking for few examples to create Tridion Items like components, pages, SG...etc using rest content manager api.I checked the swagger documentation but it was not that clear. Can you please share some examples or reference here.

I'm not sure if there are examples publicly available, but can you elaborate on what is not clear about how to create items using a POST to /api/v2.0/items ?  Also have a look at the HTTP requests sent by Experience Space frontend when you create a new item through the UI.
